# How to make python re.findall() match entire lines, but not more?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a string within an output of a subprocess call. I need the single line in which is found.

Here is the program simple.cpp that I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string a = "ABC";

int main() {
   cout << "Hello World!";
   return 0;
}
```

The command line tool and argument is:

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump simple.cpp | grep UsingDirectiveDecl
```

This produces the lines:

```
| |-UsingDirectiveDecl 0x16de688 <line:58:3, col:24> col:24 Namespace 0x16de588 '__debug'
|-UsingDirectiveDecl 0x1e840b8 <simple.cpp:2:1, col:17> col:17 Namespace 0x1378e98 'std'
```

I need the last line, I can see that it isn't indented at the beginning and contains the file name. So I need a program that can find the complete line containing UsingDirectiveDecl and has the file. I don't need anything before or after it(however may required anything afterwards at a later point).

What I have tried so far is:

```
import subprocess as subs
import re

file = "simple.cpp"

full_ast = subs.run(["clang -Xclang -ast-dump %s" % file], shell=True, stdout=subs.PIPE) # , (" > %s.xml" % title)

# noinspection PyTypeChecker
# namespace_s = full_ast.stdout.find(b"UsingDirectiveDecl") # this should shorten the list, only show the one that isnt in connection, i.e. the one without the tab


namespace_s = re.findall("^.*UsingDirectiveDecl.*$", str(full_ast.stdout))

for items in namespace_s:
    print("----------------------------\n" + items)
```

However when I run this it provides me the full output and not just a single line.

Any help is much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: See the `re.MULTILINE` flag.

Comment: Why are you using a regex that matches both lines of the example you presented? Your regex just checks that there's `UsingDirectiveDecl` somewhere in the line - it will match the next to last line as well as the last, even if you use `re.MULTILINE`